# Laravel 5.4 detecting variable in developing mode but not in production mode

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am learning laravel and for my practicing purpose I am working on a project. When that app run in local machine it work perfectly but in live server it doesn't. Whats wrong here? I know it's kind of weird but just cant figure it out.

Here is my view

```
@foreach($product_details as $product_detail)
    <div data-repeater-item class="mt-repeater-item">
        <div class="mt-repeater-row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="control-label">Title</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="indicator_id" value="{{$product_detail->id}}">
                <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" class="form-control" value="{{$product_detail->title}}" /> </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control description content" >{{$product_detail->description}}</textarea> </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-delete class="btn btn-danger mt-repeater-delete">
                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Here is Controller

```
$product_details = IndicatorDetails::where('indicator_id',$id)->get();

return view('admin.indicator.indicator_edit')->with('product_details',$product_details);
```

And Model

```
class IndicatorDetails extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','description','indicator_id'];
    public function indicator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Indicators::class);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Nothing. Just don't show anything.

Comment: try with a ```dd($product_details)``` in the controller

Comment: please check that the webserver has write permissions in storage directory and all directories below

Comment: I checked with dd($product_details) still not showing anything and permission is also perfect

Comment: If you're getting a white page, and nothing in your error log, it's a permissions problem. Check `/storage` and all files therein are writeable by your web server.

Comment: it's probably that you don't have any data in your database yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `vendor` folder of live server with my local and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing ownership of the storage directory so the cache can write to it and the `laravel.log` can be written to.

This can be achieved with the [*chgrp*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chgrp)
 and [*chown*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) commands:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score 1):

On the live server, you can try do

```
php artisan view:clear
```

To clear the view cache.

Also what happened to me before was that every time I deploy to the live server I had to restart php5-fpm.